# How to let PhpStorm know that a javascript global variable is defined?

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, phpstorm

I have twig template with that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var initParams = {
    homePage: '{{ url('_homepage') }}'
  };
</script>
```

On other hand, i have .js file with usage of initParams.homePage. The problem is PHPStorm think that my initParams is not defined. Is there the way to send defination of inTwig js variables to global PHPStorm scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

When using [jslint](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/12/how-to-lint-your-javascript-with-jslint-in-real-time/) to inspect you Javascript, you can use something like this to avoid false warnings:

```
/* global $, alert, confirm, initParams */
/* jslint browser:true */
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(initParams.homepage);
});
```

[image]

By the way if you want to use routing in your Javascript code, you should take a look at the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle).

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a way to avoid phpstorm's "unresolved variable" complaints about a global javascript variable defined inside an HTML file.

For example, if you have this global variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var initParams = {
    homePage: '{{ url('_homepage') }}'
  };
</script>
```

Then, on another js project file (for example: *phpstorm_definitions.js* ), declare a "fake" variable like this:

```
/* fake variables: used only to avoid phpstorm's complaints */
var initParams = {};
var initParams.homePage = '';
```

If the file is inside your project folder, you don't need to include the file *phpstorm_definitions.js* anywhere. Now you can use your constant in all the other files and phpstorm will not complain anymore that the constant is not defined.

It's only a trick, but works well for me